# Is it possible to wrap terraform remote state into a module and output variables from the state?

Tags: terraform, terraform-remote-state

In my terraform code I often have multiple "terraform_remote_state" to get remote state from different paths (network, security grups). So in order to avoid multiple blocks like this:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "artifactory"

  config {
    username = "${var.remote_state_config["user"]}"
    password = "${var.remote_state_config["password"]}"
    url      = "${var.remote_state_config["url"]}"
    repo     = "${var.remote_state_config["repo"]}"
    subpath  = "the_path"
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "security_group" {
  ...
}
```

I thought I would define a module like this:

```
variable remote_state_config {
  type = "map"
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "artifactory"

  config {
    username = "${var.remote_state_config["user"]}"
    password = "${var.remote_state_config["password"]}"
    url      = "${var.remote_state_config["url"]}"
    repo     = "${var.remote_state_config["repo"]}"
    subpath  = "the_path"
  }
}

output "private_subnets" {
  value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.private_subnets}"
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.vpc_id}"
```

To later use it like this:

```
module "remote-network" {
  source              = "../../remote-state-network"
  remote_state_config = "${var.remote_state_conf}"
}
...
  vpc_id = "${module.remote-network.vpc_id}"
...
```

But running results in error messages like this:

```
 module.remote-network.output.vpc_id: Resource 'data.terraform_remote_state.network' does not have attribute 'vpc_id' for variable 'data.terraform_remote_state.network.vpc_id'
```

I am using terraform 0.11.3

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but I'm going to point out, like I do in nearly every question that involves the remote state data source, don't use this. Instead use native data sources such as the `aws_vpc` data source and save yourself a ton of hassle. The remote state data source comes from a painful time before data sources (it used to be a resource that looked up state) and was the main way to look up IDs like this. Now it should only really be used as an escape hatch where a native data source doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question (since there already is one) but what you are trying to do here is what [the Module Composition guide](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html) calls "[Data-only Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#data-only-modules)", and so you might find the additional notes in that guide helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the remote state (`data "terraform_remote_state" "network"`) that you are referring here, does not have an `output` with `vpc_id` name. Which is BTW, clearly stated in the error message.

The respective Terraform code for the state file referred as `network` should have the following definition:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = "...."
}
```